# tfsjs loadGraphModel summary()

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a tfsjs model.json and weights files that I can load with loadGraphModel.
I don't know the inputs/outputs so I want to print them like we do with tfsjs LayersModel.summary()
the function doesn't seem to exist for loadGraphModel
thanks

Answer (score 0):

option 1 :
layers: undefined when I try to do console.log(model.layers)

option 2:
prints nothing for model inputs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).